# How can I create a hyperlink in C# code instead of XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, hyperlink, textblock

How can I create a hyper link in C# code that looks like the following in XAML?:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink Click="HyperLinkClick">New Hyperlink</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: This simple problem took > 30 mins to find. I have an answer but not can not post until tomorrow because of website restrictions.

Answer (score 4):

MSDN usually has very good examples. Combining the examples for [TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx) and [Hyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.aspx):

```
TextBlock textBlock1 = new TextBlock();
Run run3 = new Run("Link Text.");

Hyperlink hyperl = new Hyperlink(run3);
hyperl.NavigateUri = new Uri("http://search.msn.com");

textBlock1.Inlines.Add(hyperl);
```